# JavaScript map array of objects and duplicate object if key has more elements

Tags: javascript

I map array of objects

```
csvData = csvFileData.map(row => ({

    date: row["Sale Date"],
    orderID: row["Order ID"] || "ERROR",
    buyer: row.Buyer || "ERROR",
    SKU: row.SKU || "ERROR",
    //SKU: ((row.SKU.includes(',')) ? row.SKU.split(',')[0] : row.SKU) || "ERROR",
    qty: row["Number of Items"],
    salesTax: row["Sales tax"]
    //...
}));
```

And all OK if row.SKU has only one element like "SKU-01", but sometimes I have more elements in row.SKU like "SKU-1, SKU-2"
Now if there is no comma I would like to keep data but if it is more elements in row.SKU I would like to duplicate all data in map so many times like row.SKU elements. And the key values will change as well but only 2 ties for 1st and the rest of duplicates like:

If row.SKU={"SKU1", "SKU2", "SKU3"}
I would like to duplicate 3 times to get example:

SKU:"SKU1",
salesTax: 25

SKU:"SKU2",
salesTax: 0

SKU:"SKU3",
salesTax: 0

I hope I explained OK and you understood:)

Comment: Consider editing to add an actual log output of one or two `row`s of parsed data. Is the value of row.SKU a string that contains curly braces and commas?  The question doesn't show quotes around it.  And the parser somehow knows not to treat those internal commas as delimiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the data really looks something like this...

```
const input = [
  { 'Sale Date': 'dateA', SKU: 'SKU0' },
  { 'Sale Date': 'dateB', SKU: '{"SKU1", "SKU2", "SKU3"}' },
  // ...
]
```

Start with the OP function that processes a single row, treating the SKU prop as just another value.

```
function processRow(row) {
  return {
    date: row["Sale Date"],
    orderID: row["Order ID"] || "ERROR",
    buyer: row.Buyer || "ERROR",
    SKU: row.SKU || "ERROR",
    qty: row["Number of Items"],
    salesTax: row["Sales tax"]
    //...
  }
}
```

Add a function that produces an array of processed rows for a given row:

```
// this returns an array. the punchline is: map over this, producing
// an array of arrays, then flatten those
function processedRowsFromRow(row) {
  let rows
  if (row.SKU.includes(',')) {
    rows = row.SKU.split(',').map(sku => {
      let copy = { ...row }
      copy.SKU = sku
      // do whatever you want to set defaults in copy, e.g.
      copy["Sales tax"] = 0; // etc
      return copy
    })
  } else {
    rows = [ row ]
  }
  // run the OP's process on these
  return rows.map(processRow)
}
```

Mapping the input with that will produce an array of arrays, and we need only flatten to get the desired result.

```
const result = csvFileData.map(processedRowsFromRow).flat();
```

Demo done with dumbed-down data:

```js
const input = [
  { 'Sale Date': 'dateA', SKU: 'SKU0' },
  { 'Sale Date': 'dateB', SKU: '{"SKU1", "SKU2", "SKU3"}' }
]

function processRow(row) {
  return {
    date: row["Sale Date"],
    orderID: row["Order ID"] || "ERROR",
    buyer: row.Buyer || "ERROR",
    SKU: row.SKU || "ERROR",
    qty: row["Number of Items"],
    salesTax: row["Sales tax"]
    //...
  }
}

function processedRowsFromRow(row) {
  let rows
  if (row.SKU.includes(',')) {
    rows = row.SKU.split(',').map(sku => {
      sku = sku.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');
      let copy = { ...row }
      copy.SKU = sku
      // do whatever you want to set defaults in copy, e.g.
      copy["Sales tax"] = 0; // etc
      return copy
    })
  } else {
    rows = [ row ]
  }
  // run the OP's process on these
  return rows.map(processRow)
}

const result = input.map(processedRowsFromRow).flat(); 
console.log(result)
```